# How to make font semi-transparent with Irrlicht?

Tags: alpha, fonts, irrlicht

I'm having trouble drawing a font with an alpha channel:

```
gui::IGUIFont* font = device->getGUIEnvironment()->getBuiltInFont();

font->draw(L"C'mon, be transparent, PLEASE!!!",
           core::rect<s32>(130,10,300,50),
           video::SColor(127,255,255,255));
```

As you can see, the text should have an alpha value of 127... but it doesn't.

How *can* I draw transparent text?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that if I use SOFTWARE driver instead of OPEN_GL or DirectX, I also get your problem. But with OpenGL or DirectX it works fine. So if it is an option you can one of these drivers below:

```
video::E_DRIVER_TYPE driverType = video::EDT_OPENGL;
video::E_DRIVER_TYPE driverType = video::video::EDT_DIRECT3D8;
video::E_DRIVER_TYPE driverType = video::video::EDT_DIRECT3D9;
```

Comment: I'm using Linux, so the DirectX driver is not an option.

Comment: @George But OpenGL definitely should be. Did using OpenGL rendering fix the transparency issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple. Use StaticText. Just like this:

```
m_pText = m_pGUIEnvironment->addStaticText(
    "C'mon, be transparent, PLEASE!!!",
    rect<s32>(130,10,300,50)
);
// Set your desired color with alpha value as OVERRIDE one.
m_pText->setOverrideColor(SColor(127,0,0,0));
// And don't forget to enable it!
m_pText->enableOverrideColor(true);
```

Voela, now you have semi-transparent text. By the way, I also think that you were trying to use a white-colored text within white environment. Look at your color - transparency is useless as long as you don't use different colors for text and background. In any case, try using my example, if everything else fails.